# Understanding Cloudfronts Behavior Path pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, routes, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently using CloudFront to deliver a webpage that is hosted on an S3 Bucket.
On a subpath `/cms` I want to route all traffic to a PHP-based content management system that is running on EC2 and Apache and also has an API that is serving the data for my frontend.

I have huge trouble getting the traffic properly routed to the CMS. I added the EC2 instance as an origin and added this behavior to it.
[image]

This also reaches my Apache server. Problem is that all further paths lead to a 404 from Cloudfront. When I change the path pattern to `/cms/*` paths like `/cms/api` seem to work, but `/cms` alone will lead to a 404.
What's the correct way to just have anything with the beginning with the path `/cms` being routed to by backend?

Answer (score 1):

Because "/cms" does not match with "/cms/*"

and that is why CloudFront forward your traffic to S3 with show 404 not found error

If you want like that, set path pattern to "/cms/*" and make your your PHP application has all API with prefix /cms/

Comment: Prefixing the requests in my PHP application doesn't work yet but that's another story.

Comment: I mean prefixing in all of your APIs from INSIDE your application, not the request